# How to make nested divs appear as siblings with CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a nested structure of divs

```
<div>Content1
  <div>Content2
    <div>Content3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to look like divs with fixed width that float left?

```
<style>
  div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
<div>Content1</div>
<div>Content2</div>
<div>Content3</div>
```

Comment: The former block is missing a  `</div>`. What are you meaning to do?

Comment: If you need it to look like that, why not mark it up as that?

Comment: Maybe. It depends what your first example actually *looks like*. At the moment, [they render identically](http://jsfiddle.net/Z96kj/). You need to provide a better example.

Comment: @Kyle, @Pekka: The idea behind this is to render a nested set structure the way Mac OS renders files and folders tree. When you select a folder, each nested level appears on the right. I really need to keep the structure nested.

Comment: Your `<style>` snippet already does what you need - show the DIVs side by side, right? So what is the problem? See the JSfiddle by @thirtydot and tell us what you WANT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured how to do that with a bit of additional html and absolute positioning:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="nest">
    <div class="content">One</div>
    <div class="nest">
      <div class="content">Two</div>
      <div class="nest">
        <div class="content">Three</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
//css:
#parent {
  position: relative;
}
div.nest {
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;  
  top: 0;
  left: 200px; /*should be same as width */
  /* the next is the tricky part */ 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
/* apply custom border, padding and margin here */
div.content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do it with CSS. It's a language for defining the style of elements, not for modifying their structure. You could think about jQuery or XSLT for your case.

Comment: CSS can easily make elements look like they're structurally different (from the HTML), it's one of the main reasons for CSS existing

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin-top property to get this effect

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">

<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;margin-top:100px">
</div?

</div?
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to do anything really, this is the default behavior for block level elements.

Try to create a blank html page and insert the lines

```
<div>Content1
  <div>Content2
    <div>Content3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without any form of styling the output will be:

```
Content1
Content2
Content3
```

Which is what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Color me noobish, but couldn't you achieve something similar with an unordered list, since you're looking to nest elements? (http://jsfiddle.net/xDJAY/) Not sure if this is the structure you're looking for though.

Comment: are you sure that your markup is correct? I thought ul can't have ul as children, only li.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can nest lists within lists as [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) and [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) (under more examples) suggest. I think the new nested lists still keep the formatting of the original, so a `ul` with `margin-left:20px;` will indent a level 2 `ul` by the original 20px + the new 20px.

Comment: You're both half right. UL/OL can only have LI as children, but LI can have UL/OL as children. Here's a slightly modified version of Nathan's code (note the nested ULs are children of the LIs): http://jsfiddle.net/xDJAY/4/